# confusing!!! could you analyse parts of speech of "at around 10 AM" & "around 10 AM"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, parts-of-speech

could you analyse parts of speech of "**at around 8 AM / 8 o'clock**"?

We got these examples in [this dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/around)

> around /əˈraʊnd/  adverb
>
> We got home **at around** 8 o'clock. = (US) We got home **around
>   about** 8 o'clock. [=it was approximately 8 o'clock when we got home]

I would say, in the phrase "**at around 8 AM / 8 o'clock**" in "**I go to work at around 8 AM / 8 o'clock**",

-"**at**" is a preposition

-"**8 AM / 8 o'clock**" is a noun

-"**around**" is an adjective

-& "**at around 8 AM / 8 o'clock**" is a prepositional phrase playing a role of an adverb

Also, American people will say "**I go to work around 8 AM / 8 o'clock**". In this case, I would say:

-"**around**" is a preposition

&

-"**8 AM / 8 o'clock**" is a noun

&

-"**around 8 AM / 8 o'clock**" is a prepositional phrase playing a role of an adverb

But I am not use because in the dictionary, it says "**around**" in this case is an adverb. But I think dictionaries is not a good place to identify what part of speech of a word is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Merriam Webster link, there is this entry under **adverb:**

2 
— used to indicate that a number, amount, time, etc., is not exact or certain

The price of dinner was around [=(chiefly US) about] $50. [around=approximately]

It lasted around [=(chiefly US) about] a century. [around=approximately

The repair should cost around [=approximately, roughly] $200.

We should leave in around 10 minutes. [around=approximately]

We got home at around 8 o'clock. = (US) [around=approximately]

We got home around about 8 o'clock. [=it was approximately 8 o'clock when we got home]

To go to work **at around some** [time on a clock] is **an adverbial phrase**. It goes with (modifies they say in traditional grammar) the verb go.

Each of the examples given in that Merriam Webster's Learners Dictionary is also adverbial.

**At + [time on a clock]** is used as an adverbial phrase as it states **when "go to work" occurs.**

The preposition **at** is used with expressions of time. The use of at is idiomatic in expressions of time and associated with adverbial usage.

- It was about or around 8 o'clock =approximately modifies the time 8 o'clock.

Around or about is used in BrE and AmE and **these examples from the BBC could be either**:

> We use around or about when we want to indicate approximate times:
>
> When does his train get in?   Around / About ten o' clock usually, but
>   you can never be sure these days!
>
> What time should I come? ~ Come
>   about / around eight.

Approximately, expressed as around or about [a time on a clock or duration] is considered to be an adverb.

[BBC English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv172.shtml)

Expressing a time in English

idiomatic usage in English is: **at a time**
If a time is not definite, and is approximate, we can say: at around or about [some time].

- at around eight o'clock means: at approximately eight o'clock. Approximately or around or about in these idioms are adverbs or adverbial. See below.
- He arrived at around 8 o'clock.

  around modifies the adjective 8 [8 hours of or on the clock).
- It is around 8 o'clock.
- at around or around have the same meaning in time expressions.

You **could** say: that eight is an adjective modifying o'clock (eight hours of or on the clock), and around or about or approximately would be adverbs.

There are other interpretations possible, with **at a [time]** being viewed as a prepositional phrase. But there too: **at around x hour(s) on the clock**, it would still be an adverb modifying the hour: eight, two, three etc. o'clock.

Comment: saying that "8" is an adjective will answer my question. I thought * is a noun in this case

Answer (score 1):

Although there may be a special name for it, I believe that nowadays **around** could be called a preposition even when its complement is a number or a time, and the meaning is "approximately".

The word `approximately` is at its root a spatial term which we routinely apply to numbers and times, not just to locations.  It is related to the word `proximity`.

**around 8AM** or "approximately 8AM" refers to *an approximate time*. So there's no reason why **around 8AM** could not be the complement of **at** in its temporal sense:

> I go to work at around 8AM.

In my personal opinion, parts of speech are only labels, and labels don't really give you an understanding of a thing, not unless they're descriptive,  not merely arbitrarily adopted conventional names.